# How can I switch to already existing SQL session?

Tags: sql, hibernate, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

My code runs few sql statements that create temporary tables. My goal is to be able to browse database state within another sql console/tool/terminal having the context of application's sql session (while application thread is suspended on debug breakpoint). Application uses spring-data/hibernate/mariadb stack.

I found the way how can I achieve it by using IDE debug expression evaluator and accessing database through EntityManager instance, for example:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM rating_per_season").getResultList()
```

Imho it's quite inconvenient to find bugs in that way.
Can I somehow switch to that sql session using another console?
When I list processes through console:

```
show processlist;
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 119,
    "User": "fpsta",
    "Host": "localhost:53198",
    "db": "fp-sta",
    "Command": "Sleep",
    "Time": 1016,
    "State": "",
    "Info": null,
    "Progress": 0
  },
  {
    "Id": 148,
    "User": "fpsta",
    "Host": "localhost:54508",
    "db": "fp-sta",
    "Command": "Query",
    "Time": 0,
    "State": "Init",
    "Info": "/* ApplicationName=IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3 */ show processlist",
    "Progress": 0
  }
]
```

Now I want to run another console and then switch to session Id: 119, then continue writing my own debug sql statements.

```
MAGIC_COMMAND_SWITCH_TO 119;
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to connect to session you created from code. You can only switch sessions between opened SQL console windows. 
However, you can create a feature request on our tracker. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE